# Test all internal links

Tags: node.js, testing, web-crawler

I run a NodeJS server. I sometimes delete pages and forget to delete the references. I want to test that all internal links work appropriately. I imagine a crawler along with an npm test package, could establish a list of all the internal pages linked from the homepage and confirm that they return a 200 status code.

What is the best framework to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel.

I've used the [`hyperlink`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hyperlink) NPM package for just this purpose.

Install with:

```
npm install -g hyperlink
```

Start your web server on port 8080, for example, then run:

```
hyperlink -ir http://localhost:8080
```

`i` is for internal links only, `r` is for recursive.

Comment: You can do it locally with `hyperlink`. Just point it at your local files with `--canonicalroot` set to the real public URL.

Comment: Don't worry about that. Many high severity issues aren't really so serious, and you're not using core-js in a browser context either.

Comment: Since my last comment, the vulnerabilities got fixed and I could run the command and verify the internal links. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `hyperlink` is abandoned; in [this issue](https://github.com/Munter/hyperlink/issues/199#issuecomment-2009235099), one contributor mentions `linkinator`.

I haven't tried it because I programmed my own crawler in Python to handle cases such as images and PDFs. I reinvented the wheel because this same crawler will later serve to index the private pages of my website for a search function.